# dataLayer.push function not pushing to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to send data to my GA eCommerce instance unsuccessfully and I was wondering if anyone has run into this.

Even when I try:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];  

dataLayer.push({
'event': 'mytestingevent',
'eventCallback' : function() {
console.log("working");
}
});
```

I get the console to log "working" but nothing shows up in my Realtime Analytics.

When I preview my GTM changes, the console will log it, and the debugger shows that it fired.

All of the other events in my GTM account seem to work fine, but none of them are JS based (they're all css selector based).

The end goal is to push product data, for example:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionId': "My Test ID",
   'transactionAffiliation': 'My Test Affiliation',
   'transactionTotal': '3',
   'transactionShipping': 'My test shipping',
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'name': "Test Name",
       'sku': 'Ticket',
       'category': "Sample Category",
       'price': "3",
       'quantity': "1"

   }],
    'event' : 'datalayerReady',
    'eventCallback': function() {
      console.log("transaction event was successful");
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set event name pushed as event name trigger in GTM and associate this trigger to a Google Analytics tag. So Google Analytics tag will fire when the push is done.

Comment: Isn't my event name "mytestingevent" in the first example though?

Comment: Yes, it is the event name you have to use as name of trigger in GTM.